# dynamic bus seat layout in portrait mode

Tags: java, android

I want to create seats layout for bus booking dynamically according to the response I receive from the API provider.

The response has `row number, column number and id` for each seat. I am having trouble to figure out a way to implement the layout as the API gives me data assuming a **landscape** mode with rows & columns the other way(in **portrait** mode, rows being vertically downwards and columns being horizontal).Can someone please help?
[image: Image from API provider website, with 4 rows]
Image from API provider website, with 0-4 rows.

I've been trying to do this using a 2D array but couldn't succeed so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think 2D array is fine, but here rows should be 5, not 4 as middle row will have one seat in last column only. You can make it with conditional formatting for first and last row, where other rows will have same presentation format.

Let me know if this make sense or explain problem to know more about my idea of solving the problem.